# If-statement with pandas throws "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I am wanting to see if a particular string is present in my dataframe for one column and fire off an API if it is. code so far:

```
if new_df.col1.str.contains('string') == True:
    POST REQUEST
elif new_df.col2.str.contains('string2') == True:
    POST REQUEST

else:
  print('not good')
```

I keep getting error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is because `if-else` expressions in python are meant to compare scalar boolean values. You passed a Series.

See more in docs section on [Pandas Gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

> pandas follows the NumPy convention of raising an error when you try
>   to convert something to a `bool`. This happens in an if-statement or
>   when using the boolean operations: `and`, `or`, and `not`.

---

In this example, you can combine them into a single regex pattern `'string2?'` which indicates that `'2'` is optional.

```
def make_request():
    ...

for mask in new_df.col1.str.contains(r'string2?'):
    if mask:
        make_request()
```

If your `make_request` function returns something, you can call it in a list comp and assign back:

```
df['response'] = [
    make_request() if m else np.nan for m in new_df.col1.str.contains(r'string2?')]
```

---

Another option is using regex OR pipe to join strings in a list.

```
import re

words = ['string', 'string2']
for mask in new_df.col1.str.contains('|'.join(map(re.escape, words))):
    ...
```

Comment: is there no way to just check the boolean value on the if/else to fire off the api, without having to create a new function? I ask because each of the strings is connected to particular API endpoint with unique parameters to each string. 

Ideally, I would like to just test for TRUE/FALSE and fire off the API. Also helps show mgmt that there is a flow in place that they can understand and build upon. thank you in advance

Comment: @RustyShackleford What do you mean by "fire off the API"? Do you mean call `requests.post`? Your question isn't clear. The function call is just an abstraction, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: that is correct, call the `request.post`. but each string has a different end point. I would like to not create more functions, bc at the end of the day I handing this off to someone not technical and they would prefer the if/else logic

Comment: @RustyShackleford I need you to replace "POST REQUEST" in the question's code snippet with something more concrete that helps me understand exactly how the endpoint is different for each string. Otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: @RustyShackleford if you are trying to simulate if-else statements with pandas, your only option is np.where or np.select. Vanilla `if` statements are just not equipped to handle series as you are trying to do. I hope I can make it clear to you that you are demanding something of the language that cannot be given to you.

Comment: @RustyShackleford I also sense a fundamental misunderstanding with pandas operators here. You are dealing with logical operations, not bitwise.

Comment: you are correct, fundamental misunderstanding for sure. Studying on it now

Comment: what if I used something like to filter the string: `if df['col1'].str.contains('string1').any(): do code`